# Creating, deploying and updating RSS and Atom feeds

Tags: rss, rss-reader, atom

I've never actually maintained an RSS or Atom feed before and I just wanted to confirm that I understand their overall "*architecture*".

My *understanding* is that RSS and Atom feeds work identically, except they are slightly different file (XML) formats with slightly different standards/conventions. And that basically you point an RSS/Atom client (or "**reader**") to the URL for an RSS/Atom file, such as:

- `http://myfeed.example.com/rss/feed.xml`; or
- `http://myfeed.example.com/atom/feed.atom`

...and the RSS/Atom reader will download the file and present the feed content to the end user however it needs to present it.

Also, my *understanding* is that, to create that feed file (`feed.xml` or `feed.atom`), I just need to author it manually or with some RSS building tool and deploy it to the correct web URL. Hence every time I deploy a new/modified feed file, RSS readers will pick up those new changes.

Finally, my *understanding* is that RSS/Atom feed files will grow massive over time, retaining a full history of the feed in the form of a growing list of XML elements (one element for each new feed item, whether its a blog, a podcast or anything else).

So I ask: **is my understanding of how RSS "architecture" works correct or am I greatly misled in any way? If so, how?!** Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question isn't a great fit for Web Applications, but you are pretty much correct. Publishing an RSS feed just means publishing an XML file - most systems like Wordpress will handle it automatically. To keep the size down, most feeds will only consist of the most recent entries (either by number or date).